# How to remove kernel module if it's still in use?

Tags: samba, kernel-modules

```
[rootSERVER ~]# rmmod -f cifs
ERROR: Removing 'cifs': Resource temporarily unavailable
[rootSERVER ~]# modprobe -r cifs
FATAL: Module cifs is in use.
[root@SERVER ~]# lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64:graphics-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0-amd64:printing-4.0-noarch
Distributor ID: Scientific
Description:    Scientific Linux release 6.1 (Carbon)
Release:    6.1
Codename:   Carbon
[root@SERVER ~]#
```

I tried

```
rmmod -fw cifs
```

but it just waited for ages... (and yes, all cifs shares are "umount -l"-ed before trying to remove cifs module..)

**QUESTION**: how can I remove the cifs module??

Comment: is you or some processes current working directory still within one of the shares?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/usr/bin/sudo /bin/umount -f -a -t cifs
/usr/bin/sudo /bin/umount -f -l -a -t cifs
sleep 5
/usr/bin/sudo /sbin/modprobe -r -f cifs
pkill nautilus
```

Answer (score 7):

You can try `modprobe -r` which can resolve some dependency issues for you, while `rmmod` will do nothing else than trying to unload the module.

Also, there is an explicit kernel option on forced module unloading because it's hardly ever a good idea to do so. Can your kernel actually force a module to unload? Because if it can't the `-f` switch does precisely nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You get it to stop being in use.  i.e. unmount all of your cifs mount points.