# rmmod fails with 'module abc is in use' message

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-modules

I've tried several methods in other answers including [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41036/how-to-remove-kernel-module-if-its-still-in-use) one but couldn't find a solution.
After my driver crashed, and after the shell comes back, normally I could remove the module and insert the changed module. But this time I can't.

```
$sudo rmmod axpu_ldd_kc
rmmod: ERROR: Module axpu_ldd_kc is in use
$sudo insmod axpu_ldd_kc.ko
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module axpu_ldd_kc.ko: File exists
```

Isn't there any commands to remove the kernel module and insert anew? I'm looking for a non-programming method.

Comment: 1. Try to list modules using `lsmod | grep axpu`  then 2. Try `modprobe -rv <here-module-name>`  and see what the `-v`erbose vlag tells you.